# show data from firestore after choosing daate with datepicker flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display data depending on the date picked , but it show me error
bad state : field does not exist within documentSnapshot
this is the datepicker container

````
Container(
        child : TextField(
                   decoration: InputDecoration( 
                   prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today),), 

                  onTap: () => BottomPicker.dateTime( ),
                  onSubmit: (value) {
                    
                    dateinput.text = '$value'; 
                 
                    var now = value ;
                   print(now); } , ).show(context), ),),
     ``` 
And this is the container where I display data
````

````
    Container( 
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db.collection("eye").where("time" , isGreaterThan: dateinput.text ).snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
          } else {
              List value = snapshot.data!.docs;
            return ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.size,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var state= value[index]['state']; 
                      print(state); 
            return Container(
                  child: Text(
                    '$state',
              
                ),),  );} ); }; },) ),
 ```
````

Comment: First, does `time` actually exists or is it `timestamp`? As the error message suggests, `time` is not existent. Also, what type is `time` in the collection of `eye?: String or Timestamp? Currently, the code is comparing a String to a field which may be of type `timestamp`.

Comment: time exist on firebase , it's a String

Comment: Try this: `itemCount: snapshot.data.length` and `var state =  snapshot.data[index]['state']`. Also, please add the complete error log as text.

Comment: itemCount: snapshot.data.length this is what shows : The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the *dateinput.text*because when i replace it with a text that i already have , it shows a normal result